# Variables and file URL is not getting posted to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to create a Http request using AFNetworking that send some variables and file to server using AFNetworking. but it is not sending files and Variables too.

The request get hit to server but it does not take any parameter or file with it, i double checked it file url and parameters dic is not empty

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.app316.MWPl.backgroundconfiguration"] ];
configuration.sharedContainerIdentifier=kGroupNameToShareData;

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

    //parameters is NSDictionary With values in it
   NSMutableURLRequest *requesting=[serializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:parameters error:&error99];

 NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask4 =[manager uploadTaskWithRequest:requesting  fromFile:storeURL progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            NSLog(@"Responce== %@", response);
            NSLog(@"Success: =%@", responseObject);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
        }
    }];
    [uploadTask4 resume];
```

Comment: what is your file type? did yo set fine name correctly.

Comment: i am using this code in share photo extension. @nitin-gohel How to set file name correctly. please let me know, i am stuck from 3 days

Comment: check my answer you need to set file name as par backed team setting ask them which filename setting my server team for your file?